# Google Stepped Area Chart with custom annotation

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Thanks to [White Hat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5090771/whitehat) in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801805/google-charts-animation-doesnt-work-for-one-chart-pointing-annotations-in-the/50803820?noredirect=1#comment88641090_50803820) ,I was able to make a custom annotation for the area chart. Somehow it doesn't work the stepped area chart.

The chart draws at first everything correctly but then sets the annotation in the stepped area chart back. With help of the `MutationObserver`, the settings should be overridden when the chart is drawn but this applies just for the area chart.

How can I solve this ?

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  data1.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data1.addColumn('number', 'green');

  data1.addRows([
    [0.005, 3],
    [0.006, 6],
    [0.007, 5],
    [0.008, 8],
    [0.009, 2],
    [0.010, 5],
    [0.011, 5],
    [0.012, 4],
    [0.013, 8]
  ]);

  var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data2.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data2.addColumn('number', 'red');

  data2.addRows([
    [0.016, 5],
    [0.017, 1],
    [0.018, 3],
    [0.019, 9],
    [0.020, 4],
    [0.021, 5],
    [0.022, 7],
    [0.023, 7],
    [0.024, 3]
  ]);


  var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full',
    [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      stem: {
        length: 10
      }
    },
    title: 'Playground',
    colors: ['#007f01', '#fe0002'],
    interpolateNulls: true,
    hAxis: {
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#333'
      },
      direction: 1,
      format: 'decimal'
    },
    vAxis: {
      direction: 1
    },
    orientation: 'horizontal',

    // customize colum
    series: {
      0: {type: "steppedArea"},
      1: {type: "area"},
    },

    // legend: {position : 'left'},
    animation: {
      startup: true,
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'out',
    }
  };

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(joinedData);
  view.setColumns([0,
    1,
    {
      calc: "stringify",
      sourceColumn: 1,
      type: "string",
      role: "annotation"
    },
    2,
    {
      calc: "stringify",
      sourceColumn: 2,
      type: "string",
      role: "annotation"
    }
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(container);

  var observer = new MutationObserver(moveAnnotations);
  observer.observe(container, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  });

  function moveAnnotations() {
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var chartBounds = chartLayout.getChartAreaBoundingBox();

    var labels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    var labelSize = 0;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
      if (label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') {
        if (options.colors.indexOf(label.getAttribute('fill')) > -1) {
          labelSize = (parseFloat(label.getAttribute('font-size')) / 2);
          label.setAttribute('y', chartBounds.top + labelSize);
        }
      }
    });

    var stems = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(stems, function(stem) {
      if ((parseInt(stem.getAttribute('height')) === options.annotations.stem.length) && (stem.getAttribute('fill') === '#999999')) {
        var height = parseFloat(stem.getAttribute('y')) - chartBounds.top;
        stem.setAttribute('height', height);
        stem.setAttribute('y', chartBounds.top + labelSize);
      }
    });
  }

  chart.draw(view.toDataTable(), options);
});
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the default annotation settings for stepped area charts differ from normal area charts

for stepped, the annotations appear inside the area, which changes the color to white,
which is not a color used to find the labels and move them

an easy fix is to specify that the annotation always be outside the area...

```
annotations: {
  alwaysOutside: true,
  ...
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  data1.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data1.addColumn('number', 'green');

  data1.addRows([
    [0.005, 3],
    [0.006, 6],
    [0.007, 5],
    [0.008, 8],
    [0.009, 2],
    [0.010, 5],
    [0.011, 5],
    [0.012, 4],
    [0.013, 8]
  ]);

  var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data2.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data2.addColumn('number', 'red');

  data2.addRows([
    [0.016, 5],
    [0.017, 1],
    [0.018, 3],
    [0.019, 9],
    [0.020, 4],
    [0.021, 5],
    [0.022, 7],
    [0.023, 7],
    [0.024, 3]
  ]);


  var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full',
    [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      alwaysOutside: true,
      stem: {
        length: 10
      }
    },
    title: 'Playground',
    colors: ['#007f01', '#fe0002'],
    interpolateNulls: true,
    hAxis: {
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#333'
      },
      direction: 1,
      format: 'decimal'
    },
    vAxis: {
      direction: 1
    },
    orientation: 'horizontal',

    // customize colum
    series: {
      0: {type: "steppedArea"},
      1: {type: "area"},
    },

    // legend: {position : 'left'},
    animation: {
      startup: true,
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'out',
    }
  };

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(joinedData);
  view.setColumns([0,
    1,
    {
      calc: "stringify",
      sourceColumn: 1,
      type: "string",
      role: "annotation"
    },
    2,
    {
      calc: "stringify",
      sourceColumn: 2,
      type: "string",
      role: "annotation"
    }
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(container);

  var observer = new MutationObserver(moveAnnotations);
  observer.observe(container, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  });

  function moveAnnotations() {
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var chartBounds = chartLayout.getChartAreaBoundingBox();

    var labels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    var labelSize = 0;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
      if (label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') {
        if (options.colors.indexOf(label.getAttribute('fill')) > -1) {
          labelSize = (parseFloat(label.getAttribute('font-size')) / 2);
          label.setAttribute('y', chartBounds.top + labelSize);
        }
      }
    });

    var stems = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(stems, function(stem) {
      if ((parseInt(stem.getAttribute('height')) === options.annotations.stem.length) && (stem.getAttribute('fill') === '#999999')) {
        var height = parseFloat(stem.getAttribute('y')) - chartBounds.top;
        stem.setAttribute('height', height);
        stem.setAttribute('y', chartBounds.top + labelSize);
      }
    });
  }

  chart.draw(view.toDataTable(), options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```